# C# Window setup project

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working on window setup and deployment project in .Net VS 2010.I have created a setup file.When we install setup build in .net a step comes where user is asked to select installation folder i.e. Installation Folder step.This step has default banner text "Select Installation Folder".Also browse text box has default header text "Folder".
 Is it possible to change these default text?If so please suggest.
 Please note that I have to change only these text mentioned above not the default path or location.

Abhinav

Comment: What software are you using to create the installer?

Answer (score 3):

If you rightclick your installation project in VS2010 under the option "View" you can select the user interface. A new tab wil open with al the UI windows on it, you can change the text there.